# Error in Python TensorFlow CNN: output depth not divisible by number of groups. How can I solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, kernel

I try to implement a [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) from a [Kaggle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaggle) [machine vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_vision) course, but it throws back an error, and I cannot find it on the Internet. I can see a plot of the original car picture, kernel, but nothing after.

I attach some code:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys

import keras
from keras import layers


def show_kernel(kernel, label=True, digits=None, text_size=28):
    # Format kernel
    kernel = np.array(kernel)
    if digits is not None:
        kernel = kernel.round(digits)

    # Plot kernel
    cmap = plt.get_cmap('Blues_r')
    plt.imshow(kernel, cmap=cmap)
    rows, cols = kernel.shape
    thresh = (kernel.max() + kernel.min())/2
    # Optionally, add value labels
    if label:
        for i, j in product(range(rows), range(cols)):
            val = kernel[i, j]
            color = cmap(0) if val > thresh else cmap(255)
            plt.text(j, i, val,
                     color=color, size=text_size,
                     horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')
    plt.xticks([])
    plt.yticks([])

plt.rc('figure', autolayout=True)
plt.rc('axes', labelweight='bold', labelsize='large',
       titleweight='bold', titlesize=18, titlepad=10)
plt.rc('image', cmap='magma')

img_source = sys.path[0] + "/car_feature.png"

image_path = img_source
image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.io.decode_png(image)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(image), cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')


kernel = tf.constant([
    [-1, -1, -1],
    [-1,  8, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1],
])

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))

# Reformat for batch compatibility.
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
kernel = tf.reshape(kernel, [*kernel.shape, 1, 1])
kernel = tf.cast(kernel, dtype=tf.float32)

image_filter = tf.nn.conv2d(
    input=image,
    filters=kernel,
    strides=1,
    padding='SAME',
)

plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.imshow(tf.squeeze(image_filter))
plt.axis('off')
plt.show();
```

And an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\q621208\WorkSpace\Tensorflow\Keras\cnn_relu.py", line 64, in <module>
    image_filter = tf.nn.conv2d(
  File "C:\Users\q621208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\q621208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 7262, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Conv2D_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} output depth must be evenly divisible by number of groups: 1 vs 4 [Op:Conv2D]
```

I tried to google it, but there are mostly only "input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth:" errors described, which is most likely not relevant. I expect a following plot:

[image: Car after applying kernel].

This is an original image:

[image: Original picture]